# GNU screen clearing on vim,less,etc. exit

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I'm very new to screen but have configured my ~/.screenrc file according to various recommendations I've found on the internet. I have one issue with it though which I'm sure could be resolved very easily; I think it's a termcap setting..?

After using less, vim, top, or other programs in standalone bash (on Mac OSX 10.6), upon exiting these programs, the terminal's buffer will clear and the line above the current command line will be the previous command I entered.
However, with screen, when I exit any of these programs, the screen buffer won't clear / refresh and I'll still see what I was looking at inside that program.. Make sense??

e.g. in standalone bash (without screen):-

```
hostname:~ auser$ vim afile 
[do stuff in file, then :q to exit]
```

After exiting I'll see:-

```
hostname:~ auser$ vim afile 
hostname:~ auser$
```

But in screen:-

```
bash-3.2$ vim afile
[do stuff in file, then :q to exit]
```

After exiting I'll see a whole screen of:-

```
~  # [Empty lines in vim are represented by these tilda characters. ]
...
~  # [ Every line on the screen is one of these tildas ]
bash-3.2$   # [ This is the bottom line in the terminal ]
```

I hope that makes some sort of sense.
Any & all help much appreciated! TIA

Comment: So... what was your question again?

Comment: I just want what I've become used to... Surprise changes lead to hours of tinkering with settings I'm unfamiliar with

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer lies in the terminal capabilities of both the "real" terminal that you are using and the terminal that is presented to applications via `screen`.  Applications performing their terminal I/O via `screen` see a terminal of type `screen`.  Your "real" terminal could be anything from `xterm` to `vt100`.  (Use `printenv TERM` or equivalent to find out.)

TUI applcations like `vim` and `less` tailor their behaviour to whatever the terminal that they find themselves talking to is capable of.  This answer is far too short for a detailed exposition of the mechanics of the **terminfo** mechanism, or even for the mechanics of how programs like `vim` and `less` make use of it.  There are whole books on this stuff.  A very brief précis is that your "real" terminal is advertising a capability that the `screen` terminal is not.

Plus, of course, this has already been answered on SuperUser at length, [here](https://superuser.com/questions/136162/how-can-i-still-see-the-man-text-after-i-quit-man/136205#136205) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/137714/using-screen-commands-like-less-and-man-dont-clear-the-screen-afterwards/137751#137751) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/106637/less-command-clearing-screen-upon-exit-how-to-switch-it-off).

Answer (score 6):

put `altscreen on` in `~/.screenrc` or <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>`:altscreen`+<kbd>Return</kbd>